# Can I link my Kiln account with StackExchange?

Tags: support

Is it possible to link these accounts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Fog Creek and Stack Overflow Internet Services, except for sharing CEOs, no longer have any affiliation.

Comment: That's like saying that prgrammers and computers no longer have any affiliation except that programmers need computers to work. :p

Comment: This seems really odd, considering that you can login to both with the StackExchange open id provider.

Comment: @Andrew: That's the *whole point* of OpenID: you can use just about any provider to log into any site that uses OpenID.

Comment: I asked this over a year ago. The issue was not logging in with openid, but rather being able to link karma, question history. Linking the data, just like between stack overflow and math.stackexchange, for example.